# How to add a value to arraylist if none of the checkboxes are selected in a page in android?

Tags: android

I am working on **quiz application**. For each question there are **multiple options** should be selected. For that I have used checkboxes. **When check box is checked I am storing the checked id value in arraylist and if unchecked I am removing that id from the arraylist.** Also before this I am adding the **number of answers** for each question in the arraylist and in the next button click I am adding an "|"(or) symbol to differentiate the questions.

So for example 3 questions are displayed....then my arraylist contains

[image]

Now for the first question I selected 3 option, for second question I selected 4 options and for third question I didnt select any of the option. So for third question only the number of correct answers and the | symbol is displayed. **But now my problem if none of the checkboxes are selected I want to pass a value in the arraylist**. How can I do that? Please help me regarding this....Struggling for this since 3 days....

My Code:

```
cbs[k].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {

        if (((CheckBox) v).isChecked()) {

            selchkboxlist.add(Integer.toString(v
                    .getId()));

            System.out.println("chkboxlist size"
                    + selchkboxlist.size());

        } 
        else
        {

            selchkboxlist.remove(Integer.toString(v
                    .getId()));
            System.out
                    .println("after delete chkboxlist size"
                            + selchkboxlist.size());
            }

    }
});
```

Will be thankful in advance

Comment: What value do u want to pass to the arraylist when none of the options are selected?

Comment: why don't you store all correct answers to the list initially when screen loads..

Comment: When none of the options are selected I need to pass a value "nothing" into the arraylist. For example as showed in my code: [3,13583,13584,13585,|,4,13602,13603,13604,13605,|,2,|]--->in this for third question I didnt select the options at all. So I want to store "nothing" value between 2,|

Comment: do you have 1 question at a time?

Comment: yes at a time I am displaying 1 question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then before going to next question check your arraylist..

```
 int k=yourlist.length();
  if(Integer.parseInt(yourlist.get(k-2))<=4){
 //then it is number of answers and no check box has been checked..
  arraylist.set(k-1,new String("some value to indicate nothing"));
  arraylist.add("|");

   }
```

Comment: hi thanks for the logic...but this logic works only for this case...The question are dynamically displayed....and for ex if i didnt select options for second question out of 3 questions then this logic will not work at that time

Comment: update your array list for every question... this is what i meant to say..I think it works in all cases...

Comment: Hi Can you please explain the line "if(Integer.parseInt(yourlist.get(k-2))<=4)"

Comment: it gets the item in your array list at index k-2.. i.e the last but one item .. since the last item is your seperator "|" .. now i think your array list is of string.. so "Integer.parseInt(yourlist.get(k-2))<=4" in this integer.parseInt() converts the string value to int value cand checks if it is less than or equal to 4

Comment: Why it should be less than or equal to 4?

Comment: becuause number of options can be maximum of four...if the number is <=4 then it is number of correct answers.. or else it is the id..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10156/discussion-between-raju-and-hemanth-kumar)

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that you are creating the string at the click of some other button, where you finally form your String based upon your selchkboxlist. What you could do in that case is, at your point where you are generating this text,

```
if( selchkboxlist.length() <= 1 ){ //means that none of the checkboxes have been selected
    //Add the entry at selchkboxlist[0]
    //Add a "|"
}
```

Comment: By the way your current code should go in the else part of the above code

Comment: Hi I tried as you told...for first question I selected the options and for second question I didnt select....If nothing is selected I added the value "no".  But in my array list for the first question it added the "no"(which is wrong)...it should add to second question na...where I went wrong?

Comment: Can you show me the code that you are using to add this? Include the method where you are doing this.

Comment: hi I am trying to paste the code but it is not pasting here.....the previous code given by raju has worked for me....anyways thank you